# How to export all Digital Touch sketches from Messages?

Tags: macos, ios, messages, messages-in-icloud

Over last couple years, my girlfriend sent me hundreds of her little pieces of the art, that she made using Digital Touch.

I tap “save” every time I get one from her. Now I would like to export all of them (as vector, video or hi-res image). Is this even possible?

I don't want to scroll over a few years of our messages and save every sketch manually.

I tried searching in Library/Messages/Attachments folder on my Mac, I found photos and other stuff but not Digital Touch sketches.

Do you have an idea where to look for those?

Comment: This won't change things for the messages you have, but if you switch to using WhatApp images & videos received are automatically saved to Photos as soon as they're viewed (if not received, I haven't examined it so finely).